# React Native new architecture, C++ Turbo Native Modules

Tags: c++, react-native

I have been working on RN new architecture for 2 weeks. I'm following instructions on the official doc and I'm struggling with this C++ turbo native module on C++ section. https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/cxx-cxxturbomodules
I thoroughly follow the instructions but not be able to run the code. I run the npx react-native start but the screen is empty and return no error, sometimes it return the EPERM error, operation not permitted but I'm be able to fix this. I can't debug with react tool as well.

If anyone could make it works please help me. Thank you!

Comment: What errors do you get? Please post complete error description in the question.

Comment: Try using flipper  for debugging